# Changing the first letter in to capital using ucfirst in php

Tags: php

this is a sample of my script i cant get the first letter to be capital  this is what i have so far

```
$name = '<a href="request.php?id='.$query_row['id'].'"><h2>'.$query_row['username'].'</h2></a>';
echo $name= ucfirst($name);
```

output

Comment: Think about what `$name` is. What's its first character? There's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the value you want to have capitalized in the `ucfirst(**You value**)` function.

```
$name = '<a href="request.php?id=' . $query_row['id'] . '"><h2>' . ucfirst($query_row['username']) . '</h2></a>';
echo $name;
```

Comment: crap i didn't think about doing it like that 
thanks for the information :) 
it worked for me

Comment: @Kunz, sometimes the errors are just to simple to notice :p

Comment: @Kunz, consider accepting a answer. This will remove the question from the "Unanswered questions" queue.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution :

```
$name = ucfirst($query_row['username']);
echo '<a href="request.php?id='.$query_row['id'].'"><h2>'.$name.'</h2></a>';
```